# How do you make a search bar with JSON data and have multiple filters?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, firebase

I am basically trying to make a search bar that outputs JSON data and have the ability to choose more than one piece of data. A perfect example of this is when you go to Stack Overflow and you ask a question with the option to have up to 5 tags to describe what your question is about. I've been trying to do something like that with JSON data. If not, then are there any other suggestions on how you would do this? I am trying to make a search bar and essentially choose multiple inputs that are stored in a database and outputted on another page using the data that was inputted.

Here's an image of something similar to how it could look: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sqay.png

As you see, that's in Java so I can't really utilize that. Any help?

Thanks.

EDIT: https://codepen.io/iamtimsmith/pen/zJPzwN

`link`

Something exactly like this but using 1 search bar? I'm trying to get them into 1 but it's really difficult since it uses different classes.

Comment: There are numerous *autocomplete* or *typeahead* scripts you can use that will  make server side requests for you

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Your question is too broad and hard to answer. It involves getting the data from somewhere, parsing the response to generate your JSON, presentation and styles to display that...try to be more specific :)

Comment: I really haven't started anything because I honestly don't know where to start. I really don't care about the presentation/styling, just want to make it where multiple inputs are possible.

Comment: I've seen typeahead scripts and that's something similar to what I want, but I want the data to be stored somewhere and shown in the form at the same time.